# docx - markup / markup - docx conversion

Tags: ms-word, document, markup, docx, plaintext

I have to store some documents in the docx format, but can't stand using msword: I would like to edit some kind of plain text markup, anything except stuff based on XML (I don't like that either) and convert from/to that to/from docx.

Are there any options for this?

**EDIT:** since people think this is not programming related, I'll extend my question. What libraries do you suggest for writing a complete tex-docx/docx-tex converter?

Comment: This is a question for SuperUser.com.

Comment: @rene: well it's an option, but more of a last resort

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking .net, I'd check out the OpenXML toolkit first. There are lots of "libraries" on the internet to do this, but they all seem to just be thin wrappers around the OpenXML stuff.

You might also check out

http://openxmldeveloper.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) allows you to [create DOCX files from scratch](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/programming-with-documents.html) using text or other content and then [convert DOCX files to text](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/howto-extract-text-only.html) etc. It doesn't require MS Office to be installed on the system. And the component is a simple .NET assembly with an easy to learn and implement API. Please try and see if it helps in your scenario.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the DocxEditorKit http://java-sl.com/docx_editor_kit.html
Set the editor kit to JEditorPane, add styled text and store the document in docx format.